# How to submit a driver update to Microsoft Partner Center?

Tags: windows, driver, code-signing

I submitted a device driver to Microsoft Partner Center which successfully passed the certification.

I now want to sign a new revision of this driver (minor code changes), so I repeated the compatibility tests using HLK Studio and created a new `.hlkx` package.

What is the correct way to submit this new package?

I tried it using the "Upload new" function of the driver overview:
[image]

This gave me the following error:

> It looks like you submitted an initial package, but a derived package is required.

Unfortunately, I did not find anything about what a derived package is or how I can create one.

Answer (score 1):

You able to update drivers using DUA (Driver Update Acceptable) process. Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/user/create-a-driver-only-update-package you can find detailed instructions on how to do this. To accomplish that you'll need original driver package and registered to your account extension ID within extension INF file ([detailed info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/manage-your-hardware-submissions#update-an-hck-or-hlk-hardware-submission-using-the-driver-update-acceptable-dua-process)). After all you will get your **derived package**, derived from original driver.  As I'm aware, that called "driver only" update, that's the way to deploy fixes to your existing driver, INF file will stay the same.

For publishing of new releases (whatever major, minor or patch) of your driver I would recommend to use new submission.

Comment: According to the Microsoft instruction linked above, the DUA package may not contains any binaries (it says "The following filetypes are not allowed for DUA submissions: exe, dll, sys"). So in contrary to the answer above, the DUA submission may correct INF file, but can't correct the driver's binaries (which are usually located in SYS file)